# Qualitative study of the solution of a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having serious troubles understanding what I need exactly to solve this exercise. Here it is.

Let x($\cdot$),y($\cdot$): (${t_-},{t_+})\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ be the maximal solution of the system:
\begin{aligned}
 & x'(t)= -x(t)+y^2(t)\\
 & y'(t)= x(t)-y^2(t)
\end{aligned}
with initial condition $({x_0},{y_0})\in$ ${R_+}\times{R_+}$
I proved that x(t)>0 and y(t)>0 for every t in [0,${t_+}$) and now it says to prove, knowing that $V(x,y)=x+y$  is a first integral of the system ( i.e. that $\frac{dV}{dt}$=0) that ${t_+}=\infty$ and that x($\cdot$),y($\cdot$) are monotone functions. 
Here is my doubt. What should I do with a first integral? What informations it gives to me? I actually do not understand the intuition behind that. I read it suggests us something about the orbits, but I do not understand why and I to use the information about the orbits to answer this question. Can someone suggest me an idea? Or telling me where I can learn more about that, I find nothing at all on internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $x+y=c$ to make the second equation a scalar one,
$$
y'=c-y-y^2.
$$
As $c>0$ the right side has a positive and a negative root. By general principles for scalar equations any solutions that starts above the negative root extends to $+\infty$. Then insert into the first equation which is linear in $x$ with continuous coefficients and thus extends as far as $y$ exists.

Comment: That was really useful ! You opened my mind , thank you so much :)